# Promoted InfoPath Fields into WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, infopath, wss-3.0

I have two InfoPath forms (created in InfoPath 2007) in a WSS 3.0 site and these are setup as sontent types.

Both forms have a promoted field 'Field A' and are both bound to the same field in WSS (so that the data from 'Field A' will all display in one column when both content types are used in the same forms library.

Recently I re-published one of the forms using InfoPath 2010 (and as I always do I checked that all promoted fields were bound to their correct corresponding fields in the content type so nothing should change).  However for all new forms of one of the content types 'Field A' is not displaying when a form is saved and fields promoted.  This is the only field that has a problem, all other promoted fields are fine and it has not created a seperate field for the data, the field is still looking at the correct place in the content type.

Can anyone help me get this promoted field working again?

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to this one.  When I had re-published the form to the content type the field that i was talking about was linked to the content type for (for some reason i cannot put my finger on) needed to be pulled into the content type fields in the content type settings for the library it was linked to.

I don't know if anyone will find this useful, but thought I would post the fix / answer anyway.